# Elasticsearch geo_shape point-search returns the wrong geometrycollection documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Elasticsearch version: 6.5.0

I have question on the geo_shape point search, it looks simple, but I don't understand why.. I would appreciate any ideas..

My index schema mapping:

```
{
    "fullname": {
        "type": "text"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_shape"
    }
}
```

I create this doc that contain three 5 km circles. (Argentina, India and London)

```
PUT /location_test/region/doc123456
{
  "fullname": "Argentina, India and London",
  "location": {
    "geometries": [

    {
        "coordinates": [
          -58.4358666,
          -34.5884887
        ],
        "type": "circle",
        "radius": "5.0km"
      },

      {
        "coordinates": [
          72.8457919,
          19.1045692
        ],
        "type": "circle",
        "radius": "5.0km"
      },
      {
        "coordinates": [
          -0.1436263,
          51.5412567
        ],
        "type": "circle",
        "radius": "5.0km"
      }
    ],
    "type": "geometrycollection"
  }
}
```

When I do a search, for a point in Southampton (lat=50.909594, long=-1.404098), using the following query:

```
GET location_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            -1.404098,
            50.909594
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I got the document doc123456 back, which does not make sense, 
Since Argentina, India and London are far from Southampton.
It should not match the query, and should return no result.

The interesting thing is, then I updated the above doc, (removed one of the circles, Argentina), 
Now, the doc only contained India and London circles.

Ran the same query, I don't get the result, which is correct.

Why the doc which contained that three circles has the wrong result?

Am I using the right mapping and the field type "geometrycollection" correctly?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Could not replicate this using 6.6.0:

```
PUT location_test
{"mappings":{"region":{"properties":{"fullname":{"type":"text"},"location":{"type":"geo_shape","strategy":"recursive"}}}}}

POST /location_test/region/doc123456
{"fullname":"Argentina, India and London","location":{"geometries":[{"coordinates":[-58.4358666,-34.5884887],"type":"circle","radius":"5.0km"},{"coordinates":[72.8457919,19.1045692],"type":"circle","radius":"5.0km"},{"coordinates":[-0.1436263,51.5412567],"type":"circle","radius":"5.0km"}],"type":"geometrycollection"}}

GET location_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            -1.404098,
            50.909594
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

0 hits -- what one would expect.

---

Try running `GET location_test/_search?explain=true` and share the response.

Comment: thanks for the reply. and here is the _explanation part:
`
"_explanation": {
"value": 1,
"description": "ConstantScore(IntersectsPrefixTreeQuery(fieldName=location,queryShape=Pt(x=-1.404098,y=50.909594),detailLevel=9,prefixGridScanLevel=8))",
"details": []
}
` maybe i should try newer version too. thanks

Comment: Which version are you currently using? Maybe it's really a bug that's since been fixed.

Comment: Elasticsearch version: 6.5.0

Comment: I intalled elasticsearch 6.6.0, when I created the Mapping, encountered this "circle geometry is not supported" issue 
, found a solution (  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/circle-geometry-is-not-supported/171093  ), 

to add the "strategy" : "recursive" in geo_shape mapping.

"location": {
          "type": "geo_shape",
          "strategy" : "recursive"
}

and then ran the same query, it worked.
It returned 0 result, for the above query, that's correct.

looks like version 6.6.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: Great! I received the same error and also had to add `recursive`.

Comment: sorry, jzzfs, you are right, the answer you provided already have that "strategy":"recursive", i overlooked it. thanks